# jqGrid row alternating background

Tags: jquery, jqgrid

How can I insert alternating row background color in [jqGrid](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=start)?

Answer (score 9):

Look at the `altRows` and `altclass` [options](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:options). Beware of the typically inconsistent capitalization! This does use the jQuery UI theme if you're using jqGrid 3.5 or higher.

Answer (score 2):

```
function applyZebra(containerId) {
    $('#' + containerId + ' tr:nth-child(even)').addClass("jqgrow evenTableRow");
    $('#' + containerId + ' tr:nth-child(odd)').addClass("jqgrow oddTableRow");
}
```

ContainerId is your jqGrid ID. Call this method on the "gridComplete" event of your jqGrid.

Comment: Great solution, but it would be nice if the even/odd colors could be selected from the jQuery UI Theme.

Answer (score 2):

To use the jQuery UI theme use this code:

```
$('#'+gridName+' tr:nth-child(even)').removeClass("ui-priority-secondary");
$('#'+gridName+' tr:nth-child(odd)').addClass("ui-priority-secondary");
```

I use this code when I perform manual sorting (drag-n-drop)

Answer (score 0):

**Hello first defines the css:**

```
<style type="text/css"> 
......
.Color_Red { background:red; }
.Color_Cyan { background:cyan; } 
......
```

**Then in jqGrid ...**

```
$("#list2").jqGrid({
........
loadComplete: function() {
  var rowIDs = jQuery("#list2").getDataIDs(); 
  for (var i=0;i<rowIDs.length;i=i+1){ 
    rowData=jQuery("#list2").getRowData(rowIDs[i]);
    var trElement = jQuery("#"+ rowIDs[i],jQuery('#list2'));

// Red       
    if (rowData.Estado == 0) {
        trElement.removeClass('ui-widget-content');
        trElement.addClass('Color_Red');
    }

// Cyan        
    if (rowData.Estado == 2) {
        trElement.removeClass('ui-widget-content');
        trElement.addClass('Color_Cyan');
    }
}
},

});
```

Thus we walk the rows and apply RED to fulfill the **condition that == 0** and Cyan which satisfy the **condition == 2**.

You should change **rowData.XXX == XX** by column name and value to check.

I have it this way and it works perfectly.

Luck!

Answer (score 0):

Call loadComplete function to change background color of row in jqgrid.

```
loadComplete : function() {
    $("tr.jqgrow:odd").addClass('myAltRowClassEven');
    $("tr.jqgrow:even").addClass('myAltRowClassOdd');
},
```

for applying styles to background use below css.

```
<style type="text/css">
.myAltRowClassEven { background: #E0E0E0; border-color: #79B7E7; }
.myAltRowClassOdd { background: orange; }
</style>
```

**Or**

For changing row font in jqgrid see click  below link

[How can I change Background colour and Font of any row in JQGrid?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/22505167/1624035)

Answer (score -1):

[Here's how you do it](http://www.drewtech.net/2009/06/alternating-row-style-with-jqgrid/):

```
$("#myGrid").jqGrid({
   ...
   gridComplete: function() {
       var _rows = $(".jqgrow");
       for (var i = 0; i < _rows.length; i += 2) {
           _rows[i].attributes["class"].value += " alt";
       }
   }
});
```

Comment: *Way* too much work. This feature is already built into the grid. No need to reinvent it.